# How to navigate to ionic app by adding app url path to the website url?

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am working in angular and ionic projects.Here I have a website and an ionic3 app with firebase integration.I need to navigate to ionic app web link on giving url path of ionic app after the website link in the url.
How can I implement this in my angular code?